# Cross-Domain login using NodeJS and PassportJS

Tags: node.js, express, session, cookies, passport.js

I am working on a NodeJS app that has the login on a different domain / port.
In my case, I have the login server on localhost:3000 and the application on localhost:3001.

Since I am using PassportJS, when I go to localhost:3001/profile I check if the user is logged in using

```
function isLoggedIn(req, res, next)
{
    if (req.isAuthenticated())
    {
        return next();
    }

    res.redirect('http://localhost:3000/login');
}
```

After login, I send and get an SMS code, I validate the code and then I get redirected back to http://localhost:3001/profile. The problem is, once back, I get redirected to the login server again.

```
app.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local-login',
{
    successRedirect: '/sendsms',
    failureRedirect: '/login',
    failureFlash: true
}),
function (req, res)
{
    if (req.body.remember)
    {
        req.session.cookie.maxAge = 1000 * 60 * 30;
    }
    else
    {
        req.session.cookie.expires = false;
    }
});
```

From /sendsms I get redirected to /validate:

```
app.post('/validate', function (req, res)
{
    console.log("SMS Code: " + req.body.smscode);

    if (checkSMSCode(req.body.smscode, req.user))
    {
        console.log("OK");
        res.redirect('http://localhost:3001/profile');
    }
    else
    {
        console.log("NOK");
        res.redirect('/login');
    }
});
```

This is the app.js on my authentication server:

```
'use strict';

var debug = require('debug');
var express = require('express');
var session = require('express-session');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var passport = require('passport');
var flash = require('connect-flash');
var helmet = require('helmet');
var request = require('request');
var connect = require('connect');

var app = express();


/*
 * Connect to the database.
 * Pass passport for configuration
 */

require('./config/passportHelper')(passport);


/*
 * Setup the express application
 */

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(helmet());


// Setup ejs templating
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs'); 

// Setup passport sessions
app.use(session(
{
    secret: 'mysecretkey',
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true
}));

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
app.use(flash());


/*
 * Setup the resources
 */

app.use('/css', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public/stylesheets')));
app.use('/js', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public/scripts')));


/*
 * Setup the routes
 */

require('./routes/index')(app);
require('./routes/login')(app);
require('./routes/signup')(app);
require('./routes/profile')(app);
require('./routes/logout')(app);
require('./routes/redirect')(app);
require('./routes/ticketing')(app);
require('./routes/object')(app);
require('./routes/sendsms')(app);
require('./routes/validate')(app);


/*
 * Catch 404 and forward to error handler.
 */

app.use(function (req, res, next)
{
    var err = new Error('Not Found');
    err.status = 404;
    next(err);
});


/*
 * Development error handler.
 * Will print stacktrace.
 */

if (app.get('env') === 'development')
{
    app.use(function (err, req, res, next)
    {
        res.status(err.status || 500);

        console.log("ERROR");

        res.render('error',
        {
            message: err.message,
            error: err
        });
    });
}


/*
 * Production error handler.
 * No stacktraces leaked to user.
 */

app.use(function (err, req, res, next)
{
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error',
    {
        message: err.message,
        error: {}
    });
});

app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);

var server = app.listen(app.get('port'), function ()
{
    console.log('Express server listening on port ' + server.address().port);
    debug('Express server listening on port ' + server.address().port);
});
```

I'm pretty sure I'm missing something very obvious, especially since it's the first time I am doing something like this (standalone authentication server) but I can't figure it out and I seem to be running around in circles.

At first, everything was designed as a single application and since /profile was on the same domain, there was no issue.

Any ideas or hints?